# How to play a media file using loop with some delay?

Tags: android, multithreading, media-player

I am trying to play a raw media file using a loop. I have written a synchronized method to play the media file. This is working on emulator but not on real device.

I have created a simple bean for Question for which sound needs to be played.

```
public class Question {
private String mQuestionString;
private int mSoundFile;
private int mAnswer;
private int mQuestionNo;

public Question() {

    mQuestionNo = 0;
    mQuestionString = "";
    mSoundFile = 0;
    mAnswer = 0;
}

public Question(int mQuestionNo, String mQuestionString, int mSoundFile,
        int mAnswer) {
    super();
    this.mQuestionNo = mQuestionNo;
    this.mQuestionString = mQuestionString;
    this.mSoundFile = mSoundFile;
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;
}

public String getQuestionString() {
    return mQuestionString;
}

public void setQuestionString(String mQuestionString) {
    this.mQuestionString = mQuestionString;
}

public int getSoundFile() {
    return mSoundFile;
}

public void setSoundFile(int mSoundFile) {
    this.mSoundFile = mSoundFile;
}

public int getAnswer() {
    return mAnswer;
}

public void setAnswer(int mAnswer) {
    this.mAnswer = mAnswer;
}

public int getQuestionNo() {
    return mQuestionNo;
}

public void setQuestionNo(int mQuestionNo) {
    this.mQuestionNo = mQuestionNo;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Question " + mQuestionNo + ". " + mQuestionString;
}

}
```

This is my code in the activity

```
public class LQActivity extends Activity{

    private Vector<Question> mQuestions = null;
private TextView tvQuestion = null;
private Button btnSubmit = null;
private Button btnNext = null;
    ...

  private void prepareQuestions() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    mQuestions = new Vector<Question>();
    mQuestions.add(new Question(1, "Count the number of the Tabala played",
            R.raw.q1, 5));
    mQuestions.add(new Question(2,
            "Count the number of the persons visited temple", R.raw.q2, 3));
    mQuestions
            .add(new Question(3, "Count the number of frogs", R.raw.q3, 6));
    mQuestions.add(new Question(4,
            "Count the number of the cuckoo on the tree", R.raw.q4, 8));
    mQuestions.add(new Question(5, "Count the number of the flute played",
            R.raw.q5, 7));

}

private synchronized void playQuestion(Question question) {


    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, question.getSoundFile());

    mMediaPlayer.start();
    try {
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }
    }
            mMediaPlayer.release();
        }

}
```

The problem is `mMediaPlyer.create()` is returning null

I am not getting the exact problem. your help is appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mMediaPlyer.create() is returning null
```

The reason  is due to a corrupt mp3 file or use of unsupported file,Check the link android supported [media format](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: no the file format is mp3 only and even if I give direct resource from raw folder same error continues. BTW thanks for reply

Comment: @chaitanya you got Create() null,so it will occur for corrupt file!!

Comment: Hi I missed out that angle. :( thanks again. BTW in what scenario the file gets corrupted? can it be avoided?

Comment: @chaitanya check this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20int%29